# Solr Facets: How to set Facet.Limit to (-1) unlimited in Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq from code

Tags: linq, solr, sitecore, sitecore7

Solr Facets: We have a case where we need to show all facets where the count is more than 100. We need to set facet.limit = -1 to get unlimited facets if we are browsing on Solr browser.
We are using to Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq to set facets from code, which doesn't have implementation to set facet.limit and we have increased ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults as 20000 in solr.index.config file but it could not help full to get all facets.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to change the default Facet.Limit value in the solr config.xml file.
However, be careful as high numbers would impact the performance.